# Best way to loop the angular flex layout with two rows?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, layout

I would like to know how to do the ngFor with two rows in angular flex layout.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="container" fxLayout fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
        <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="50%">
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item-label">
                {{item.name}}
            </div>
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item-value">{{item.value}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-2" fxFlex="50%">
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item-label">
                {{item.name}}
            </div>
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item-value">{{item.value}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" fxLayout fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
        <div class="item item-3" fxFlex="100%">
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item-label">
                {{item.name}}
            </div>
            <div fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item-value">{{item.value}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here its looping but each time its printing 3 values for every index. I would like to print index 0 value of first column, index 1 on second column and index 2 value on second row.

Answer (score 4):

I've created for you an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhebvk), based on your requirements.

The correct way would be :

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
  <!-- you can use ngClass to manage 'item-1' or 'item-2' style -->
  <div class="item" fxFlex="50%" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item-label">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <div fxLayoutAlign="center" class="item-value">{{item.value}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `wrap/nowrap` property on the `fxLayout` directive does everything, because childs are set with `fxFlex="50%"`.

I put out `fxLayout.xs` to render it correctly on stackblitz.

Here is [@angular/flex-layout documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview)

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. It should work if we contain only three values. I have edited the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flexlay). Here I would like to show 3rd and 6th values in full row.  But its equally divided into two columns.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhebvk) ? I've added a type and flex property to define which length should have the item...

Comment: New version based on your code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhebvk), look at the fourth solution but you'll need data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The "wrap" parameter in the "fxLayout" is used to wrap the child content with the help of "fxFlex"